# Getting a confirmation from kernel when setting from userspace

Tags: wifi, linux-device-driver, netlink

I am using nl80211 and Netlink sockets to send a message to the kernel to set something. To be specific, I am issuing vendor specified commands from userspace to `set` RF sector in `wil6210` driver. For the `set` commands, the userspace application does not request any information from kernel. I want to know if I should expect a message from kernel indicating whether the `set` command is done successfully or not?

If there is such confirmation reply from kernel to userspace, What attributes should I look into? Is it a standard reply for all `set` requests?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, to pass a value to a kernel driver, use a file on `/sys`.

To use a file on `/sys`, you have to call a sysfs-creation function like `sysfs_create_group()`.
Many drivers of kernel use this way.
If you use a file on `/sys`, you can also pass an error return, if necessary.

I think using a file on `/sys` is more general and more canonical way than using `set`.